# PHP Sort Order Process Codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg

i use php codeigniter to manage video using FFMPEG, but i dont know how to delete original video after convertion successful.

```
if(!($_FILES["upload_video"]["type"] == "video/mp4"))
    {
    $prename = $r.'.'.$ext;
    $video = $prename.'.mp4';
    $directory_path  = "/home/templates/videos/".$prename;
    $directory_path_full = "/home/templates/videos/".$prename;
    exec("ffmpeg -i ".$directory_path_full." ".$directory_path.".mp4"); 

    // Delete original format video
    $this->load->helper("file");
    unlink($directory_path_full); 

    }else{
    $video = $r.'.'.$ext;
    }
```

When i use "unlink" it work good to delete file, but the video is corrupt (maybe php directly delete it when converting progress)
So, can you help me to create sort order php process for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it
in ffmpeg was created good command and i just use

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$directory_path_full." ".$directory_path.".mp4 &&  rm ".$directory_path_full." ");
```

or in shell

```
ffmpeg -i tmp.file new.file && rm tmp.file
```